Optimal resource allocation in brms: Balancing cores and threads
I often encounter the following rstan recommendations:

For local, multicore CPUs with sufficient RAM, it’s suggested to use options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores()) to auto-detect available cores.
When using within-chain parallelism functions like reduce_sum() or map_rect(), set rstan_options(threads_per_chain = 1).

Currently, I’m running a complex Bayesian model in brms on a 12-core machine, and I plan to use 4 chains. For the best performance, I’m configuring it as follows:
options(mc.cores = 4,
        brms.backend = 'cmdstanr')
rstan_options(threads_per_chain = 3)

With this setup, 4 cores are allocated to run chains and 3 threads per chain, ensuring that the 12 cores are fully utilized (4 chains * 3 threads = 12 threads). I’d like to know if this setup is optimal or if there might be a more efficient configuration for balancing mc.cores and threads_per_chain.

There is no general answer, it depends on whether within-chain parallelization is helpful which depends on the cost of calculating the log-likelihood. See the brms vignette. I'm not sure setting rstan_options will do anything for the cmdstanr backend however, you may just want to use cores = 4, threads = threading(3) in your brms call. You can try whether this is faster than e.g. just running chains = 12, cores = 12 with fewer sampling iterations per chain.
